# Example code for blowfish encryption

Tags: c, windows, encryption, blowfish, twofish

I need to encrypt a `char*` string in C using blowfish or twofish in Windows.
I can't find a straight forward solution for that.

I don't want to install something like OpenSSL; I need it be a standalone as possible.
Unfortunately Googling for C code results in C# and C++ code.

Can anyone give me a straightforward function for encryption/decryption?

Comment: I voted to close as off topic - this seems to be a request for an external library, unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @Duncan: its a request for an example to use blowfish without an external library (e.g. `openssl`)

Comment: So you're looking for a hunk of C code that implements blowfish or twofish, using just primitives?

Comment: And have you tried converting the c++/c# code to plain c? What problems are you having with that?

Comment: @Duncan: i'm looking for a code that be able to encrypt a text in blowfish

Comment: @Kevin: i'm not very familiar with C++/C# so no i didn't

Comment: You usually don't have to be very familiar with a language to read it and figure out what's happening. Give it a try and tell us what constructs you don't understand. And both of them are heavily based on C, if they don't use objects there's a decent chance you'll be able to copy it verbatim (or with just a couple changes).

Comment: http://bit.ly/1dySBvb Did you try the _I'm Feeling Lucky_ button when you were Googling for it?

Comment: Am I allowed to say that the combination "using C" and "not very familiar with C" is nearly as scary as "need encryption" and "can't type 'blowfish c' in google"? Not meaning to offend you, but you may have decided for a project that is a bit too enthusiastic. If something needs encryption, usually at least a moderate skill level and a firm understanding of basic tools is needed, so it does not end in a total desaster.

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at "https://www.schneier.com/twofish-download.html" on Bruce Schneier web site?  He has reference implementations, as well as optimized implementations of the algorithm.  It's been a few years since I looked at it, but you might find it useful.

Comment: Also, searching with `filetype:c` is often helpful. For example, https://www.google.com/#q=blowfish+filetype:c. There's pages of hits for the search, and all are source code (on the first page).